# Can one talk during Kaddish when he is not part of the Minyan?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, kaddish

One is not supposed to talk during Kaddish. See [Mishna Berurah](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F%20%D7%A0%22%D7%95&pgnum=173&hilite=) below Siman 56.

Does this apply to someone who is not Davening in the particular Minyan where the Kaddish is being said, but happens to be in the room at that time? If he also should not talk, what about if he is in a different room but hears Kaddish being recited?

Comment: Can someone explain how to set up a link in a question? I had trouble with it. Thank you.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links.

Comment: Why do you think having davened recently in that location would affect the relevant law? Please [edit] to clarify

Comment: Perhaps it is a part of Davening like any other where one needs to be Yotzeh. Therefore one who already Davened need not listen.

Comment: @Ploni I went to the link you posted when writing my question but I had trouble getting the link to work.

Comment: @danf what would you say if one is learning in the room, should he also stop learning during Kaddish?

Comment: @Earl first of all, one doesn't need to talk while learning. Second, I know that there is an explicit opinion mentioned in SA that one is not allowed to learn during *chazarat hashat"z*.

Comment: @DanF A) As a general rule, one is supposed to say with his lips what he is learning. B) I believe you are correct regarding learning during Chazaras Hashats. However I am talking about  someone who already Davened. I think the Halacha is talking about someone Davening in that Minyan, as he needs to be listening to the Shliach Tzibur & not distracted by anything else.

Comment: Are women allowed to talk during Kaddish? Because essentially this is asking the same thing.

Comment: @Earl Re: A) - that's correct. But, I believe that the term used for learning as well as *Shema* and *Amidah* is *Hishmiyah L'Oznov*. That means "audible to your ears" - meaning, specifically, your OWN ears and not to others! Why people yell out parts of davening is a bit of a mystery, to me. The only one that should be "yelling" (NICELY) is the chazzan.

Answer (score 2):

In reading the Mishnah Berurah commentary in several places in the exact chapter that you cited, it seems quite obvious that one may not talk when he hears Kaddish being recited. It makes no difference if he is praying with the minyan or even if he is in a nearby room, whene her hears Kaddish. he must respond *Yehi Shmei Rabbah*.

Summary of major points, all coming from Mishna Bereurah commentary on OC 56:

- א - says that one must be careful not to speak at all when Kaddish is said and concentrate and say with all his might *Yehi Shemei Rabbah*
- Rama"h at end of par. 1 says that someone who arrives late (which means, he is not part of the current service, now. He will be once he begins his own davening.) must respond to whatever part of the Kaddish that the cong. is saying even if he hasn't heard its beginning.
- Mishnah Berurah ו - says that in a place where there are 2 minyanim next to each other, if he hears both say Kaddish as a single voice, he responds to both of them. True, he is responding to the one he is in, but, at the same time, he is responding to the one that he is NOT part of, as well.

The point is, that it seems clear that responding to Kaddish is paramount.

What I've mentioned addresses specifically answering Kaddish. It is a given, that one should not be talking in shul while davening occurs, whether he is part of the current minyan or not, irrespective of Kaddish.

Comment: The Ramah you quoted is obviously talking about someone who didn't Daven yet but will be joining the Minyan now. If he already Davened it wouldn't say he is coming late. I agree with you that answering Kaddish is extremely important, I am just not sure if what you brought from the Mishna Berurah & Ramah answers my question. Like I posted earlier perhaps Kaddish is a part of Davening, in which case someone who already Davened need not answer, although it's proper to.

Comment: @Earl You've raised an interesting point regarding what Rama"h said. I need to re-explore that. However, there are 3 points I would disagree with: 1) Kaddish is not specific to "part of davening" as we say Kaddish Derabanan after learning. Rama"h does not exactly distinguish which Kaddish he's referring to. 2) Rama"h and MB mentions what to do when you hear Kaddish in another room while davening in your room. He says that you are answering for both simultaneously. Well, you are davening in your room, but you didn't daven in the other room, yet you should answer Amen. (continued.)

Comment: 3) MB says that one should run to answer Kaddish. The language there, to me, implies that's true even if you have davenened. As a mater of fact, the general language used in both Shulchan Aruch and Gemarah mentions the overall importance of answering *Yehie SHmei Rabbah* and the reward for doing so, that, I'm not convinced that either place was limiting it to just the time or area you are davening in.

Comment: I agree with all you have written. Kaddish is of utmost importance. Thanks for the insightful back & forth conversation.